# Redirect loop when trying to login to /wp-admin/

Tags: loop, login

Stuck in an infinite loop when trying to log in to my wordpress site. I type in the URL/wp-admin and then it loops me back to the regular website, not the admin login page.

I have tried with http and https to no luck...

Comment: take backup & Delete .htaccess File

Answer (score 24):

I found a solution. In `wp-config.php` add:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

In my situation, I migrated to *https* from *http*, and use plugin *Rename wp-login.php*

My `wp-config.php` contained the lines:

```
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
```

Without the line `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);`, a redirect loop occurs.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the issue for me as well. I think using Cloudflare also plays a part in causing this redirect loop.

Comment: In theory you never want admins to be logging in over an insecure connection, so turning off FORCE_SSL_ADMIN is usually a bad idea.

Comment: This did not help.

Comment: This was helpful to be able to stop the redirect in order to log into the WP-Admin and correct the site url there as needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Additionally when using CloudFlare Flexible SSL, check this out https://community.cloudflare.com/t/endless-redirect-with-wordpress/3914/6

Comment: @hermanschutte, can you explain how Cloudflare could cause the issue? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry, you'll be back in quick if you follow these steps one at a time, until one succeeds!

1. **Clear you cookies** - Clear your local browser cookies (follow instructions for whatever browser you are using.
2. **Deactivate All Plugins** - Rename /wp-content/plugins/ directory to plugins_OLD
3. **Revert Back to the Default Theme** - Go to /wp-content/themes/ directory and rename your current theme directory to anything (like theme_OLD).
4. **"Delete" .htaccess File** - Again using FTP software, rename this to .htaccess_OLD
5. **Update Site URL** - In wp-config.php add these lines (using your url of course):

`define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

Comment: I found the same instructions elsewhere on web, but skipped #5 because it seemed too simple.  Step #5 solved my problem on localhost.

Answer (score 5):

I've just solved an issue with this symptom. The 8 key and salt values must be present in the `wp-config.php` file or admin doesn't work.

I had these in the file, but because of how I dynamically generated `wp-config.php` the values were appended at the bottom of the file. Any constant definitions (`define()`) must be placed above the `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` line.

Wordpress gave no error or logs to indicate it was missing config items. This also stopped `'WP_DEBUG', true` working. Once I moved all of these higher in the `wp-config.php` file everything started working.

Comment: I [had fun](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/343810/login-redirect-to-loop-with-reauth-1-cookie-expiry-set-to-1-year-in-past) with this…

Answer (score 1):

I spend hours trying to resolve this, did everything.  Eventually notice a log about group write permissions on the wp-login.php file.  Looked and the server file permissions were 664 .. changed them to 644 and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after moving my site from a production host to localhost for dev testing. Steps that work for me in production didn't work locally. For instance, when using Chrome as my browser, entering

**http://localhost/wp/wp-admin** would redirect to

**http://localhost/wp/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp%2Fwpcurrent%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1**.

Entering my username/password would redirect back to the second link with a new username/password prompt.

**Firefox resolution:** add to wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://your_url.com'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://your_url.com');
```

**Chrome resolution:** Remove the redirect querystring from the login page: e.g. **http://localhost/wp/wp-login.php** .

Yes, I'm fairly new to Wordpress and I'm not 100% certain of the internal route for logins and redirects after authentication, so much trial and error was involved to find these two solutions. Hopefully they can help someone else.