# Login redirect_to loop with reauth=1, cookie expiry set to 1 year in past

Tags: login, cookies, site-url

(I've resolved this - sequencing error in wp-config.php - thanks to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/325933/42868) elsewhere).

---

I've moved a site dev to production and everything is working correctly *except* the login form, which is stuck a loop with this URL:

> /wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

- It's an **https://** site (though the dev site was as well) and uses a www. prefix

With Chrome Devtools and *Application > Storage > Cookies* (or *Network* with 'Preserve log' ticked) open: **the authentication cookies are being sent** - I'm getting about 16 in all (examples below) from the *wp-login.php* response (straight after clearing cache) including multiple wordpress_sec and WordPress_logged_in.

**However every cookie has an expiry date of 1 year ago (July 2018) so immediately disappears.**

I've been going through the WP Core source code, the `time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS` line mainly seems to be for situations where the password has been reset.

**I verified that** `$user = wp_signon( array(), $secure_cookie );` **is completing successfully and the user was being sent to /wp-admin, but then redirected from there back to wp-login.php*

Also:

- `WordPress_test_cookie` has no expiry. It has the correct domain (including www.), `/` for the path and is Secure, according to devtools
- `siteurl` and `home` option values are correct, FQDN with correct protocol and URL definitely spelt correctly (I used `wp option get/set`, but have also defined them at the top of *wp-config.php*)
- user/password combinations I've tested are definitely valid (deliberately incorrect entry gives error as expected). I also used WP CLI to reset them, create a test account
- I've tried toggling the theme back to the default one
- I've tried using WP CLI to regenerate the permalinks and delete transients
- I'd regenerated the salts (**the location of the salts in the config file turned out to be the solution, see my answer**)
- I've tried deactivating various plugins
- It's not a multisite, but I tried defining `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` anyway - that *was* my resolution to a similar problem with a different WPMU install
- `WP_DEBUG_LOG` is true and nothing is being written to wp-content/debug.log
- I've been testing in Chrome with a cleared cache
- The rest of the site is working fine (served via Nginx with a working LetsEncrypt cert).

Any suggestions?

WP core 5.2.2, Nginx 1.14.2, PHP 7.3.4-2, MySQL 10.3.15-MariaDB-1 on Debian 10.0 (Buster)

**Sample cookies in response:**

```
set-cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; path=/; secure
set-cookie: wordpress_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/wp-admin
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/wp-admin
set-cookie: wordpress_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/wp-content/plugins
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/wp-content/plugins
set-cookie: wordpress_logged_in_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wordpress_logged_in_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wp-settings-0=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wp-settings-time-0=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wordpress_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wordpress_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wordpressuser_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wordpresspass_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wordpressuser_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wordpresspass_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
set-cookie: wp-postpass_e3a619e8946da863a424fa3e2712b99b=+; expires=Fri, 27-Jul-2018 18:40:34 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
status: 200
```

Answer (score 3):

This was caused simply by the salts in `wp-config.php` being at the end of the file, after the call to wp-settings.php (they were inserted by an Ansible script) rather than above the line:

> /* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

:(